# Randomly booting to initramfs

Tags: boot

Sometimes when I boot my laptop running 14.04 it comes up with the "ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/... Does not exist."

This only started happening after I installed new RAM. It doesn't happen all the time either, sometimes if I wait a while after I get this error it will boot up fine and continue to do so for a week or so until this happens again.

I have read posts about this error, but I didn't see any that explained what was going on with my machine.

First off, what does this mean, and what could be causing it? Is certain RAM not compatible with Ubuntu? This seems weird.

Secondly, what are some possible solutions?

EDIT: I have replaced the ram and it is now still giving me the error. I have reinstalled Ubuntu several times, tried boot repair and nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
echo "sleep 60" > /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/delay_for_raid_array_to_build_before_mounting
chmod a+x /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/delay_for_raid_array_to_build_before_mounting
update-initramfs -u
```

Taken from here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2241430

basically you are trying to introduce a delay in bootup (60 seconds in the example given here) for the system to find/load any devices that may take a little longer to get ready, such as an mdadm raid1 / raid device / encrypted disk / or other random issue that may be caused by the system booting too quickly for something and devices it needs not being ready yet.

I had the problem on a fresh install of a 14.04.1 LTS server with mdadm raid1 (in degraded mode using only one drive to begin with until I had the 2nd drive to put in).

If you can't boot at all, you may need to use a mix of steps using a LiveCD to be able to do the following steps in your installation, or you could try the "boot from first hard-disk" in the Livecd boot menu and see if that works first.

Otherwise, using some examples from the following thread might help using a LiveCD to get the following steps done on a "broken" system that won't boot:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2241460

I assume you may have moved on or otherwise solved this by now (4 week old thread), but figured I would document a fix that worked for me in a hopefully related scenario, so others might find it easier.

This is the google search that I used to find the solution I used:
mount mounting dev/disk/by-uuid on /root failed device or resource busy